# Is linearity required for MLE equivalence to least squares with Gaussian noise?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares

In many places its claimed that in order for maximum likelihood to be equivalent to least squares one of the requirements is a linear model (in addition to heterodecasicity, iid and Gaussian noise). I do not understand why linearity is required. For example here it does not appear that linearity is required:

[https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/SpecAnal/Maximum_Likelihood_Sinusoidal_Parameter.html](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/SpecAnal/Maximum_Likelihood_Sinusoidal_Parameter.html)

Perhaps I am misunderstanding what is meant by linearity? I would think that linearity means the estimated parameters are linearly related to the measured variable (x(n)), but perhaps this is incorrect? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't what you linked explicitly stating at the end of the page when the equivalence holds?